# Orchard 1.7 Media Library create thumbnails for videos

Tags: thumbnails, orchardcms, video-thumbnails, media-library

When uploading a video (e.g. YouTube) in Orchard 1.7 with the new Media Library, the library creates thumbnails for your videos.
I want to create a similar library with thumbnails of my videos where the thumbnails would be links to the video detail page. I can't figure out how to create the thumbnails for the videos, only images.

The alternate view page "Content-Videos.Summary.cshtml" I'm creating looks like this:

```
@{    
var mediaPart = ((Orchard.MediaLibrary.Fields.MediaLibraryPickerField)Model.ContentItem.Videos.Video).MediaParts.FirstOrDefault(); 
}
<a href="@Url.Content("~/" + Model.ContentItem.AutoroutePart.Path)">
<img src="@Display.ResizeMediaUrl(Width: 200, Height: 200, Mode: "crop", Alignment: "middlecenter", Path: mediaPart.MediaUrl)" >
</a>
```

I've been looking at the "Media-OEmbed.Thumbnail.cshtml" file in Ochard.MediaLibrary/Views but I'm still stuck.
The file looks like this:

```
@{
ContentItem contentItem = Model.ContentItem;
var media = contentItem.As<MediaPart>();
var oembed = contentItem.As<OEmbedPart>();
}

@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oembed["thumbnail_url"])) {
<div class="media-thumbnail media-thumbnail-@contentItem.ContentType.HtmlClassify() mime-type-@media.MimeType.HtmlClassify()">
<img src="@Display.ResizeMediaUrl(Width: 200, Height: 200, Mode: "crop", Alignment: "middlecenter", Path: oembed["thumbnail_url"])">
</div>
}
```